# What is the initial re-transmission timeout for TCP?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

I am interested in Linux. I have a client and a server. Lets say the client is trying to connect to the server (which is down). What is the initial re-transmission timeout value? Does it exponentially back off?

Lets say the server is now trying to connect to the client. The server receives the SYN packet and sends a SYN ACK. But the client dies. What is the re-transmission policy for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the initial re-transmission timeout value?

It is both platform-dependent and configuration-dependent.

> Does it exponentially back off?

All retransmissions in TCP do that.

> What is the re-transmission policy for this scenario?

See above.

Comment: Is it different for differnt linux flavors? Can you please give me some numbers for any platform of your choice.

Comment: @Bruce It was 3 seconds in Windows NT, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223450, but you can Google as well as I can.